# Bit operator logic in java class Pattern

Tags: java

In java.regex.Pattern there is the following declaration:

```
public final class Pattern implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    private static final int UNIX_LINES = 0x01;
    private static final int CASE_INSENSITIVE = 0x02;
    private static final int COMMENTS = 0x04;
    private static final int MULTILINE = 0x08;
    private static final int LITERAL = 0x10;
    private static final int DOTALL = 0x20;
    private static final int UNICODE_CASE = 0x40;
    private static final int CANON_EQ = 0x80;
    private static final int UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS = 0x100;

    private Pattern(String p, int f) {
        if ((f & ~ALL_FLAGS) != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown flag 0x"
                                               + Integer.toHexString(f));
        }
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to understand the logic to check whether there is an unknown flag.

As hex string

```
ALL_FLAGS  => 00000000000000000000000111111111
~ALL_FLAGS => 11111111111111111111111000000000
```

Now, if I use the flag 0x03 (which should not be allowed), then

```
0x03 & ~ALL_FLAGS => 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

So that flag would be allowed as well, although not defined. Only flags > 511 will not be allowed.

What is the reason behind that logic?

Comment: 0x03 is `UNIX_LINES | CASE_INSENSITIVE` - why should this not be allowed?

Comment: the flag values are chosen in such a way to allow their combination, otherwise they would just have been numbered 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. "Bit mask" was the term to search for. Found a good explanation [here](https://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/)